# service get data but not work angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm using service get data but not work . here is my code

services.js

```
  angular.factory('myServices',myServices);
        myServices.$inject=['$http'];


            function myServices($http){
   return  {
           getAllShop:getAllShop
            }
            function getAllShop(){
                    return
                     $http.get('data.json')
                        .then(onSuccess);
                    function onSuccess(response){
                        return response.data;
                    }

                }

            }
```

here is my controller.js

```
shopController.$inject=['$http','myServices'];
function shopController($http,myServices){
    var vm = this;
    vm.mydata=[];
        function getAllShop(){
            return myServices.getAllShop().then(function(data){
                vm.mydata = data;
                return vm.mydata;

            })

        }
}
```

and here is my html

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in vm.mydata">
 {{data.name}}
{{data.price}}
```

but nothing show and no error in console.log . Where's my wrong . Pls help me

Comment: Is something returned by your request ? Do you call your controller function "getAllShop()" ? Because you don't return it from your service (in your service add the line: return {getAllShop: getAllShop};).

Comment: @Groben i add return but not work too

Comment: As I said, do you call your function from the shopController ? You need to call it to be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never called `getAllShop()` in your controller, only defined it. Just add this line into your controller and you should be good:

```
function shopController($http,myServices) {
    ...
    getAllShop();
}
```